Force break timer for macOS
Is there a break timer for macOS that FORCES you to take a break (i.e. when it goes off there's no way to disable it)?
The only app I've found that passes the command+q test is TimeBomb, but then that app, for whatever reason, decided to add a very convenient 'end break' button to the top right corner.
